# Tilix-terminal configuration for symfony-console-autocomplete

Tags: symfony, terminal

i successfully installed [bamarni/symfony-console-autocomplete](https://packagist.org/packages/bamarni/symfony-console-autocomplete) with `composer require bamarni/symfony-console-autocomplete`

i did not found a shell configuration file (`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`) for adding:

`eval "$(symfony-autocomplete)"` as explained to do so in this documentation.

i hope to get a easy way to get auto-completions if using terminal. for example for:

`~/symfony/example$ bin/console <TAB>`

if needed i will change the terminal emulator for Linux kUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

that's workaround enables to add Symfony commands using [copyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) into console or where ever you want. A bit more awkward to use than typical console auto-completion via <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.
I also configured two [copyQ-Shorcuts](https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) for faster access the list (<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> open my copyQ and <kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> [opens tab-list](https://github.com/hluk/copyq-commands/issues/41#issuecomment-874480263) ):

```
cd ~/symfony/example; copyq removetab symfonyBinConsole; copyq show symfonyBinConsole; rm ./symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh; ./bin/console > symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh; ./bin/console debug:autowiring >>  symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh; sed -ri 's/\s*([^ ]+)(.*)/copyq tab symfonyBinConsole add "\1 # \2"/' symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh ; chmod +x ./symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh ; ./symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh; rm ./symfonyBinConsole2copyQ.sh
```

[image: copyQscreenshot]

## sh-script easier to read:

this sh-script does almost the same thing, but is a little easier to read than a one-liner

```
# copyq needs started first!
cd ~/symfony ; #  subfolder if you maybe use such a subfolder for your syfony projects
copyq removetab 'symfonyCon&sole'; 
copyq show 'symfonyCon&sole'; 
[ -f tmp.2copyQ.sh ] && rm tmp.2copyQ.sh; # <= removeFile if exist
clear; 
echo "# hi from SH-generater. thats first line. \n" > tmp.2copyQ.sh; 

example/bin/console > .binConsole.tmp.sh; 
example/bin/console debug:autowiring >> .binConsole.tmp.sh; 
# sort -buo .binConsole.tmp.sh .binConsole.tmp.sh; # <= tested 2021-0804_0747-10 and has no effect here.
sed -ri 's/\s*([^ ]+)(.*)/copyq tab "symfonyCon\&sole" add "bin\/console \1 # \2"/'  .binConsole.tmp.sh ; 
cat .binConsole.tmp.sh >> tmp.2copyQ.sh; 

NO_COLOR=1 symfony help > .symfony.tmp.sh; # maybe help is same as list 2021-0804_0802-05
NO_COLOR=1 symfony list >> .symfony.tmp.sh; # maybe help is same as list 2021-0804_0802-05
sort -buo .symfony.tmp.sh .symfony.tmp.sh; # <= 586 with. 741 without. tested 2021-0804_0747-10 ==> has effect here.
sed -ri 's/\s*([^ ,]+)(.*)/copyq tab "symfonyCon\&sole" add "symfony \1 # \2"/' .symfony.tmp.sh ; 
cat .symfony.tmp.sh >> tmp.2copyQ.sh; 

# sort -buo tmp.2copyQ.sh tmp.2copyQ.sh; # <= just a prettify and not needet. 476 lines 2021-0804_0753-48 without 741

chmod +x tmp.2copyQ.sh ; 
./tmp.2copyQ.sh ;
# [ -f tmp.2copyQ.sh ] && rm tmp.2copyQ.sh; # <= removeFile if exist

# kate tmp.2copyQ.sh # < open in editor
# kate 2copyQ-generator.sh # < open in editor
```